# Adding Git to existing Visual Studio Web Forms project

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012.3

I have a legacy Win Forms application in a Web Forms solution / single project in Visual Studio 2012.3 now.

I would like to add it to Git Source Control. So I right clicked the project and selected 'add to source control' - VS came up with a message saying it had created a repository.

However when I edit a file I am unable to right click it and 'commit', its greyed out (I have got this to work in new MVC 4 apps under Git).

What am I missing?

Comment: Which extension (and version) are you using for version control?  Is there a .git subdirectory where your .sln file is located?

Comment: Commit will be greyed out unless you put a description of the changes in.